# Airflow: how to specify condition for hourly workflow like trigger only if currently same instance is not running?

Tags: python, airflow

I have created an workflow (contains few tasks). It is hourly execution. Workflow should be triggered only if another instance of workflow is not running at same time. If it is running, workflow execution should be skipped for that hour.

I checked with "depends_on_past" but couldn't get it.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `max_active_runs` on your `DAG` to 1 and also `catchup` to `False`

Comment: Thanks @joeb. Will check with this

Answer (score 0):

From the [official Airflow documentation for trigger rules](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#trigger-rules):

The `depends_on_past` (boolean), when set to True, keeps a task from getting triggered if the previous schedule for the task hasn’t succeeded.

It will work if you use it in the definition of the task. You can pair it with `wait_for_downstream= True` as well to guarantee that the new run's instance will not begin until the last run's instance of the task has completed execution.

```
task_depends = DummyOperator( task_id= "task_depend", dag= dag, depends_on_past= True )
```

However another way to work around this assuming that you only need the latest run to work is using the [Latest Run Only concept](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#latest-run-only):

Standard workflow behavior involves running a series of tasks for a particular date/time range. Some workflows, however, perform tasks that are independent of run time but need to be run on a schedule, much like a standard cron job. In these cases, backfills or running jobs missed during a pause just wastes CPU cycles.

For situations like this, you can use the `LatestOnlyOperator` to skip tasks that are not being run during the most recent scheduled run for a DAG. The `LatestOnlyOperator` skips all immediate downstream tasks, and itself, if the time right now is not between its `execution_time` and the next scheduled `execution_time`.